# JFrame multiple screens

Tags: java, swing, jframe, screens

I have been programming in Android and I switch between specific screens using intents. I have always wondered how to do this in Java, when I click a button switch to a different screen. Is there a way to specify multiple `JFrames` or would I have to delete all of the objects off one frame and then add some?

Comment: @Op. I removed the android related tags since your question is a Swing question, and not an Android question (I did also add the Swing tag).

Comment: You can have multiple JFrames in a Swing application, and you can bring different frames to front, and/or hide certain frames depending on what the user does. How you do that depends a bit on what architecture you are using, but you should look into the MVC architecture, and also read a bit about IOC since that usually makes it easier to implement MVC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `CardLayout` for "switching content". See [How to use CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

And instead of Intents in Android, you should use `Action` in Java Swing. See [How to use Actions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

Comment: See also [CardLayout Demo.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665156/calling-awt-frame-methods-from-subclass/5786005#5786005) for an example.